# Mouse cursor freaks out when Xbox 360 controller connected

Tags: xbox-360, usbhid

I think I screwed something up in a HID library when trying to install a PS3 controller not long ago, as the PS3 controller never worked right, and now when I try to connect an Xbox 360 controller, the mouse cursor jumps to the top-left corner of the screen and neither it nor the keyboard will respond.

any idea what I ought to purge to fix this? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. I Removed `xserver-xorg-input-joystick` and used jstest to correct a mis-mapped axis.